# The dual-monitor settings ignored when using XFCE

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, radeon, xfce, dualhead

I have two monitors and a ATI Radeon 5750 video adapter.
Using ATI's catalyst control center I am able to configure the displays so that the desktop spans over the two monitors.

The multi-desktop settings are preserved when logging with KDE. It was also working properly with gnome and unity (when i used to have them installed).

BUT: when logging in with XFCE  the second monitor is cloning the first (instead of creating an extended desktop).

I can enter into ATI's control center and reconfigure the desktop.  But the settings are lost when i logoff !

Does anyone have any clue about what is happening here ? 
Why does the Xfce desktop uses some wrong multi-monitor settings ?

This problem appeared first when i upgraded to 11.10 (about 2 months ago). And now after upgrading to 12.04 the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Follow instructions [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/how-to-use-multiple-monitors-in-xubuntu.html) to update to Xfce 4.12., which will provide a new minimal display settings window, and options for dual monitor, which were not present in Xfce display manager in older versions.

[image]

[image]